# pixels to meter conversion on browser image

Tags: javascript, html, image, maps

I have an image of indoor map on my browser and I could calculate the coordinates of random points on the image in pixels. I want to convert these coordinates to meters. For example, I want to convert (123, 246) in pixels to (10, 20) in meters.

I have the width and height of the building in meters and also the size of the image in pixels.  What would be the best way to calculate the pixels to meter ratio so that I can convert these back and forth?

I am using mostly JavaScript to do all this.

Comment: JavaScript and Java are not really related; if you're doing most of your work in JavaScript, please don't add the Java tag unless there's a good reason to.

Comment: 100 pixels are usually about 26.5mm, but it's not a consistent conversion, it all depends on the DPI of the screen, and it sounds like you really just want to create some sort of image that is to scale ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not creating an image. I need to know the points inside the indoor map in meters as I have to do some further calculations based on those coordinates. Moreover, these calculations can not be correct if my coordinates in meters are not correct. The only things that I have is the width and height of the iamge in pixels and meters (actual building dimensions). So if I place certain points on the image I should be able to figure out how  far from the top left corner of the image the points are ( in (x,y) coordinates )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the width of the building in pixel and meters, the ratio meters:pixels is simply `widthInMeters / widthInPixels`.  Your question suggests you have the width of the image, but not that of the building, but also that you are able to calculate the location of random points in pixels.  Therefore all you have to do is measure the width of the building in pixels as it is represented in the image, then divide the actual width by this number.

You should note that a pixel is not a continuous measure like a meter, so the precision is going to be limited by your scale (e.g. 6.3 pixels looks the same as 6 pixels).  Also, if the image has not been accurately drawn or encoded, the ratio horizontally could be different to the one vertically.